# DownloadManager: How to check when a new download started from queue

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager

I want to enqueue several files to a downloadmanager's queue, and be notified when a new download starts so I can do something at that moment.

I see that it broadcasts an intent when a download has completed, but not when one has started. How can I run some code specifically at the moment of a new download starting?

Comment: you cannot, what you can do is to poll via `DownloadManager#query(DownloadManager.Query query)` for pending / running requests

Comment: @pskink so I'd have to keep querying periodically and monitoring changes manually?

Comment: i dont see any other way but periodically polling, do that once per second and nobody will be hurt